# Given component holder MainActivity does not implement interface GeneratedComponent or interface GeneratedComponentManager

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, dagger, dagger-hilt

I am strugling with hiltViewModel for some reason. I went many similar posts but with no success and I'm getting frustrated slowly, maybe you will find something that I've overseen.

The trouble begins when I want to use the hilt to inject my ViewModel but I can't figure out why...

This are my deps:

```
  plugins {
      id("kotlin-kapt")
      id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.47" apply false
  }  

  buildscript {
      dependencies {
          classpath("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.48")
      }
  }

  dependencies{
    //Dagger Hilt - dependency injection
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.48")
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.1.0-alpha01")

    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.48")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.48")

    runtimeOnly("androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03")

    //general
    ...
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.2")
  }
```

Then I create the App:

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class MyApp : Application() {
}
```

And implement it in the AndroidManifest

```
...
<application
        android:name=".MyApp"
...
```

This is the MainActivity:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val navController = rememberNavController();

            MyAppTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "home") {
                        composable("home") {
                            MyView()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That's the ViewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(
) : ViewModel() {
   ...
}
```

And that's the point where it crashes:

```
@Composable
fun MyView(
   viewModel: MyViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
   ...
}
```

The error I get is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Given component holder class com.example.MainActivity does not implement interface dagger.hilt.internal.GeneratedComponent or interface dagger.hilt.internal.GeneratedComponentManager
```

I can't figure out why. Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

@Update
I found out that this works:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val navController = rememberNavController();

            MyAppTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    IncomeView()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So why could this provoke this error:

```
NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "home") {
  composable("home") {
    MyView()
  }
}
```

and without the NavHost not?

Comment: can you remove apply part from the plugin and try? id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.47"  like this?

Answer (score -1):

I faced a similar kind of issue. I forgot to declare the application name in the manifest and it working fine now.

```
 <application
    android:name=".HiltApplication"
```